# How to access AWS cloudHSM from node.js application?

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudhsm

I want to access cloudHSM cluster from my VPC network via node.js application.
My main usage is to manage crypto keys.

I can't find APIs to manage keys in CloudHSM with node.js.

I can only find these APIs to manage the CloudHSH cluster:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudHSMV2.html

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same question